# I can't create a spring boot project because of my network where I work

Tags: maven

I want to create a project using spring boot create, but when I give it to finish the dependencies it does not execute because I get that the execution time timed out
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFoDR.png)

To which my conclusion is that the network where I work is blocking some downloads, someone knows how to configure the spring tools or if there is any way to configure the pom.xml so that the project dependencies can be downloaded.

Comment: Hi. Is proxy configuration in your IDE correct?

Comment: Hi ,Install local maven and add in the .m2 a file with the name "settings.xml", and there I put the proxy configuration that this using

Comment: It has nothing to do with spring that you’re behind a corp firewall.

Comment: The error it gives me is that it cannot connect to load the dependencies properly, investigate well and it does not create the job status, I imagine because I am on a corporate network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two ways to create a spring boot project.
1 - Using STS
2- https://start.spring.io/

if you are facing issue with eclipse/STS, then choose second option.

Comment: The error it gives me is that it cannot connect to load the dependencies properly, investigate well and it does not create the job status, I imagine because I am on a corporate network.